# Flash adding \r to input textbox, is this normal?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am setting a string variable to the value of a input box in my movie but Flash also seems to be adding a \r (Carrage Return) to the end of it's value. This is not something i am typing.

Is this normal or am i doing something wrong, i can't seem to find where it is coming from.

If this is normal, what is the best way to prevent this from happening as it is causing me problems when i use this variable later.

I am using Flash CS4, AS3.

Thanks,
Kohan.

Comment: how are you adding the value to the textbox, can you supply some code?

Comment: Will supply some code when i get home. But I am basically saving the MyGlobal.loggedUser = username.text; MyGlobal was a package i found on the internet that is used for making Global Variables.

I did a trace on username.text and MyGlobal.loggedUser and both have the Return at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deselected Auto Kern on the textbox and the problem was resolved.